# I want to open a URL in Browser by clicking on android app's icon in my mobile. How can i do that in android studio 2.2?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to create an android application that can only perform one function i.e. to open a specific URL in a web browser. I don't want to make any screen or button I just want the user to click on the icon of the application and it will open URL in the browser. Please let me know how can i do that.

Below is the image of the android studio without any layout.

[Please Look at the Image and let me know where to place the code?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc3FA.png)

Comment: First upgrade your implementations before starting coding. its showing error of deprecated implementations .

Comment: How could i do that?

Answer (score 2):

in AndroidManifest you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to be able to access the internet
then put this code in MainActivity for java :
`Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")); startActivity(browserIntent);` and for kotlin  `val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")) startActivity(browserIntent)` change [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) according to the address you want to go